# Ubuntu 21.10 on HP Envy Help- Help with missing features

Tags: hp, fingerprint-reader, display-rotation

I was hoping you might be able to help me out.

I recently installed 21.10 on my HP Envy x360.

I've got the Ryzen 5 4500u with radeon graphics.

I was wondering about a few features that I'm hoping have support, but I've been unable to conquer with my Google-fu.

1. Does anyone know how to get the auto-rotate working?
2. Any way to switch it to "tablet mode" and disable keyboard input?
3. Touch fingerprint scanner? I can't seem to get it working.

Thank you!

Comment: For the fingerprint reader, the Terminal output of `sudo lsusb` will be required. A lot of HP readers are unsupported, though ...